# Django Rest API urlsplit error

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am trying to set up an API using Django Rest, I've attempted to use the quick start guide, but all I can get is this error:

`'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlsplit'`

I can't find any reference to this error on the internet, let alone how to solve it.

Here is my urls file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import admin

from rest_framework import routers, serializers, viewsets

admin.autodiscover()


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'email', 'is_staff')


class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('logs.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
)
```

Full traceback:

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET
>
> Django Version: 1.6 Python Version: 2.7.6 Installed Applications:
>   ('rest_framework',  'south',  'django.contrib.admin', 
>   'django.contrib.admindocs',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles',  'logs', 
>   'django_nose') Installed Middleware:
>   ('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
>
> Template error: In template
>   /Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templates/rest_framework/base.html,
>   error at line 87    'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no
>   attribute 'urlsplit'    77 :
>   rel="nofollow" title="Make a GET request on the {{ name }}
>   resource">GET
>
> 78 :
>
> 79 :
>
> 80 :                                         title="Specify a
>   format for the GET request">
>
> 81 :
>
> 82 :
>
> 83 :
>
> 84 :                                     {% for format in
>   available_formats %}
>
> 85 :
>
> 86 :
>
> 87 :                                                 href=' {%
>   add_query_param request api_settings.URL_FORMAT_OVERRIDE format %} '
>
> 88 :
>   rel="nofollow"
>
> 89 :                                                title="Make a
>   GET request on the {{ name }} resource with the format set to `{{
>   format }}`">
>
> 90 :                                                 {{ format }}
>
> 91 :
>
> 92 :
>
> 93 :                                     {% endfor %}
>
> 94 :
>
> 95 :
>
> 96 :
>
> 97 :
>
> Traceback: File
>   "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in get_response
>     139.                 response = response.render() File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py"
>   in render
>     105.             self.content = self.rendered_content File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py"
>   in rendered_content
>     59.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, media_type, context) File
>   "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/renderers.py"
>   in render
>     733.         ret = template.render(context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     140.             return self._render(context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     134.         return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     78.             return node.render(context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     123.         return compiled_parent._render(context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in _render
>     134.         return self.nodelist.render(context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     78.             return node.render(context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py"
>   in render
>     62.             result = block.nodelist.render(context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     78.             return node.render(context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py"
>   in render
>     305.                 return nodelist.render(context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     840.                 bit = self.render_node(node, context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/debug.py"
>   in render_node
>     78.             return node.render(context) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py"
>   in render
>     196.                         nodelist.append(node.render(context)) File
>   "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py"
>   in render
>     1125.                     return func(*resolved_args, **resolved_kwargs) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py"
>   in add_query_param
>     86.     return escape(replace_query_param(uri, key, val)) File "/Users/taylorhobbs/.virtualenvs/Workout_log/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/templatetags/rest_framework.py"
>   in replace_query_param
>     22.     (scheme, netloc, path, query, fragment) = urlparse.urlsplit(url)
>
> Exception Type: AttributeError at / Exception Value:
>   'Module_six_moves_urllib_parse' object has no attribute 'urlsplit'

Comment: Please edit your question and add the full traceback (the error message).

Comment: Make sure your installed version of six is up to date

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try upgrading your version of Django.  Base 1.6 doesn't have this function, but 1.6.3 does.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.6.3/

Comment: FWIW, you'll probably want to upgrade to the latest (1.6.8 as of this writing) - there are numerous security fixes that you'll want to have.

Comment: Confirmed yes, I'm updating the Django REST framework docs for the minimum supported versions now.

Answer (score 1):

So I've solved my issue, for the time being anyway, I changed my DRF version from 3 to 2.4 and it seems to have solved my issue. If anyone else has a legitimate answer please share it.

Comment: "I changed my DRF version from 3 to 2.4" - As per the answer above - just upgrade your Django 1.6 to the latest 1.6.x release.

Comment: I downgraded DRF and now I'm getting a different issue ('ListField' is not a serializer field). *sigh*

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's exactly the error I'm getting. I'm using python 2.6 , Django 1.6. I'll try to change to DRF 2.4

P.S: when I used Python 3.4 and django 1.7 with latest DRF. there was no error. 
P.S.S - removed 3.0.1 and installed 2.4.4 and then added this to settings.py. It worked.

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```